# File parsing and data management

Tags: c, parsing, file, cyclomatic-complexity

This is part of a two-part post ([Part 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112471/file-parsing-and-data-management-part-2)).

---

Here, I have two recent projects that parse a file. The first uses a loop that's kind of hard to follow, and the second uses "modes" to decide what to do.

#### Project 1: A "bookmark manager" for managing URLs easier than a text editor.

#### The data structures:

```
typedef struct {
    char *text;
    int length;
} string;

typedef struct {
    string *path;
    string *title;
} url;

typedef struct {
    url **urls; // An array of pointers to urls
    int length;
    int sel_url;
    int modified;
    char *filename;
} urllist;
```

For the data, I am considering using a linked list instead of an array.

#### The parser:

```
void parse_file(char *fname, urllist *ul){
    /* Dumb char-by-char parser that follows the syntax "URL[Title]"
     * [Title] is optional. If left unspecified, then the url is used as
     * a title instead.
     *
     * There's some basic idiot-proofing:
     * 
     * 1. Empty lines are ignored (lazy-ignore)
     *    Rather, '\n' and ' ' are skipped if they begin a line.
     *    " http://google.com" is still valid; it'll just take two
     *    iterations to extract anything from it
     *
     * 2. lines beginning in '[' or '#' are fully ignored (full-ignore).
     *    So you can write comments like "#this" or "[this]". The
     *    'comment char' has to be the first character on the line. If
     *    there is a space before it, for example, the parser will think
     *    it's a url.
     */
    int c;
    url *u;
    FILE *f = fopen(fname, "r");

    while(1){
        c = fgetc(f);
        if(c == -1){ /* Check EOF */
            break;
        }
        if(c != '\n' && c != ' ' && c != '[' && c != '#'){
            /* Thanks to the EOF check, I have to add the first char
             * NOW, while I still have it. This is also an opportunity
             * for a sanity check */
            u = new_url();
            string_push_char(u->path, c);
        } else if(c == '#' || c == '['){ /* full-ignore */
            while((c = fgetc(f)) != '\n');
            continue;
        } else { /* lazy-ignore */
            continue;
        }
        while(1){ /* Step through individual line */
            c = fgetc(f);
            if(c == '\n'){
                /* Line ends without title, copy path to title */
                string_copy(u->title, u->path);
                break;
            }
            if(c == '['){
                /* Title specified. */
                while(1){ /* Get it. */
                    c = fgetc(f);
                    if(c == ']'){
                        while(fgetc(f) != '\n');
                        break;
                    }
                    string_push_char(u->title, c);
                }
                break;
            }
            string_push_char(u->path, c);
        }
        url_push(ul, u);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

It works, but I feel like it could be done better. As I said earlier, it's hard to follow. You can tell because it's littered with comments, which I personally try to avoid unless describing a block of code as a whole.

#### An example file

> ```
> # Cool sites
> http://google.com/search?q=help+with+bananas[Google: banana help]
> http://stackoverflow.com[Stack Overflow]
>
> # YouTube stuff
> http://youtube.com
> ```

#### Result

> ```
> [Google: banana help                  ]
>  Stack Overflow
>  http://youtube.com
>
>
> http://google.com/search?q=help with bananas
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The code sure must be streamlined. I didn't find any better way to review but to rearrange the code and put my notes as comments.

```
    // First, you test the character against the same condition twice.
    // A more direct way would be to do it once

    if (c == '#' || c == '[') {
        while (fgetc(f) != '\n')
            ;
        continue;
    }
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\n')
        continue;

    // Notice that here you still have `c` intact (so the comment about
    // NOW is misleading). Time to initialize the `url`:

    u = new_url();

    // Since you have the first character of the `u->path`, a correct
    // idiom is a `do {} while ();` loop:

    do {
        string_push_char(u->path, c);
        c = fgetc(f);
    } while(c != '\n' && c != '[');

    // Here `c` is the reason of loop termination. Test it and proceed accordingly:

    if (c == '[') {
        while ((c = fgetc(f)) != ']') {
            string_push_char(u->title, c);
        }
        while(fgetc(f) != '\n')
            ;
    } else {
        string_copy(u->title, u->path);
    }
```

This almost it. The code parses the well-formed file, but will fall into an infinite loop if, for example, the title-closing bracket is missing.

As a side note, `isspace(c)` is strongly preferred to a manual testing.