# File parsing and data management - follow-up

Tags: c, parsing, file, cyclomatic-complexity

This is part of a two-part post ([Part 1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112467/file-parsing-and-data-management)).

---

Here, I have two recent projects that parse a file. The first uses a loop that's kind of hard to follow, and the second uses "modes" to decide what to do.

#### Project 2: A working map renderer that I plan to implement the game of Picross with.

This one uses "modes" to control the flow of the loop. I feel it is much more elegant, but wonder if this is the best way to do it.

The project is nowhere near finished, but I think this is in-line with the posting guidelines, since the part I care about is fully functional.

#### The data structures:

```
struct picross_data {
    char *name,
         *map;
    int width,
        height;
};
```

#### The parser:

```
enum pfmode {
    mode_find_name,
    mode_get_name,
    mode_find_width,
    mode_get_width,
    mode_find_height,
    mode_get_height,
    mode_get_map,
    mode_finish,
};

void
parse_file(char *fname, struct picross_data *pd)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(fname, "r");
    char fbuf[10000] = "",
         *fbp = fbuf,
         *nbuf = calloc(sizeof(char), 100),
         *nbp = nbuf,
         numbuf[10] = "",
         *nmbp = numbuf,
         *mapbuf,
         *mbp,
         c;
    enum pfmode m = mode_find_name;
    /* This function uses four buffers for parsing the file. 
     *     fbuf[10000] for the file contents,
     *     nbuf[100]   for the name,
     *     numbuf[10]  for numbers,
     *     mapbuf[w*h] for the map
     * The modes are self-explanatory. They make it easy to focus on one section at a time without an over-complicated hacked-together while loop
     */

    while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) *(fbp++) = c;
    fclose(f);

    fbp = fbuf;
    while(m != mode_finish){
        switch(m){
            case mode_find_name:
                if(*fbp == '"'){
                    m = mode_get_name;
                }
                fbp++;
                break;
            case mode_get_name:
                if(*fbp == '"'){
                    m = mode_find_width;
                    pd->name = nbuf;
                } else {
                    *nbp = *fbp;
                    nbp++;
                }
                fbp++;
                break;
            case mode_find_width:
                if(*fbp == '['){
                    m = mode_get_width;
                }
                fbp++;
                break;
            case mode_get_width:
                if(*fbp == ','){
                    pd->width = atoi(numbuf);
                    nmbp = numbuf;
                    m = mode_find_height;
                } else {
                    *nmbp = *fbp;
                    nmbp++;
                }
                fbp++;
                break;
            case mode_find_height:
                while(*fbp == ' ') fbp++;
                m = mode_get_height;
                break;
            case mode_get_height:
                if(*fbp == ']'){
                    pd->height = atoi(numbuf);
                    mapbuf = calloc(sizeof(char), pd->width * pd->height);
                    mbp = mapbuf;
                    m = mode_get_map;
                } else {
                    *nmbp = *fbp;
                    nmbp++;
                }
                fbp++;
                break;
            case mode_get_map:
                if(mbp-mapbuf >= pd->width * pd->height){
                    pd->map = mapbuf;
                    m = mode_finish;
                }
                if(*fbp == '.'){
                    *mbp = 0;
                    mbp++;
                }
                if(*fbp == '*'){
                    *mbp = 1;
                    mbp++;
                }
                fbp++;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I feel that while this is definitely more verbose, it is far easier to follow.

#### Example File:

> ```
> $ cat puppy.pc
> "Puppy" [10, 10]
>
> * * . . . . . . * *
> * . * * . . * * . *
> . . * * . . * * . .
> . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . * * . . . .
> * . . * * * * . . *
> * . . . * * . . . *
> . * . . * * . . * .
> . . * * . . * * . .
> . . . . * * . . . .
> ```

#### Result

> ```
> $ ./a.out puppy.pc
> Puppy (10 x 10)
> * *             * * 
> *   * *     * *   * 
>     * *     * *     
>
>         * *         
> *     * * * *     * 
> *       * *       * 
>   *     * *     *   
>     * *     * *     
>         * *
> ```

#### Another example:

> ```
> $ cat test
> "Smiley"[5,5]......*.*......*...******
> ```

#### Result:

> ```
> $ ./a.out test
> Smiley (5 x 5)
>
>   *   *   
>
> *       * 
> * * * * *
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Jamal, looks much better without the erroneous syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

## Naming

Please, use adequate names. (e.g: who reads your code doesn't know what `fbuf` means).

## Parser

- Any reason why you can't use `fgets()`? If you need every char in order to inspect it or modify or whatever else then use `fgets()`.
- You're risking buffer overflow if the user inputs `10000` characters or more.
  You need to dynamically allocate memory, using `malloc()` and `realloc()`.
- Use `sscanf`. Checking the return result of `sscanf` would be a good idea as well. The *scanf() functions return the number of items read. Don't compare the return value with EOF.
- You can use `fseek` and `ftell` to calculate the file size for you without having to read every character.

Fair example:

```
long fsize(FILE *fp) {
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long bytes = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    return bytes;
}
```

These functions are part of standard C (stdio.h), so this is portable.

- Take care of `pre`/`post` fixes for variables.
- In the last `case`, you don't need to use `break;`.

Comment: As for the `break;`, it's a habit of mine to be explicit and leave room for additions. The last time I aggressively byte-counted like that, I spent the next three hours debugging what ended up being a missing comma. So thanks, but I'm not too concerned about the *size* of my source code.

Comment: As for `fgets`, I considered it, but when I realized I'd have to calculate the size of the file to `fgets` it into a buffer, it kind of seemed redundant, as fgetc will do the job without needing to read the file twice.

Comment: As for the limited file size, I totally forgot about that. I'll definitely `calloc/free` it with a larger size. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @B1KMusic what I mean is that it's good to use `break` for the `case`s, but not in the last one: there won't be any necessity. The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n` from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by `s`. No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after EOF.

Comment: But then there's the "what if"s. What if I need to add another case after the last one? Missing the `break;` would thus be bug-prone, because if I forget to add it,  then it will bleed into the next case...

Comment: As for `fgets`, how do I know the length of the file without reading it (with fgetc) at least once? Unless you're suggesting something like`fgets(fbuf, SOME_MACRO, f);`.

Comment: Well, I'm reviewing the code as it is. I'm just saying that `break` isn't technically needed after the last alternative (which, mind you, doesn't have to be default: it is perfectly legal, and sometimes even useful to put the default branch first); whether your code falls through the end of the switch-case or `break`s out at the end of its last branch has the same result.
However, if you want you can (for preference) add it every branch, including the last one, with a `break`statement.

Comment: @B1KMusic: `fread()` gives you as much control as `fgetc()`, and has the advantage of being able to read more than one character in a single I/O operation. In fact, memory permitting, you can read the entire file into an array and do all of your processing in memory. This has significant performance advantages.

`fread()` is **often** used to read fixed-length data records directly into structs, but you can use it to read any file. It's my personal choice for reading most disk files.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that `break` isn't needed by the *compiler*, and, as you pointed out at the end, one can put the `break` anyway (and the compiler will optimize it out) if they prefer. And, I prefer to remain as explicit as possible to avoid bug-prone code, which is why I leave the `break` in there. That's just defensive coding practice that I've learned over the years.

Comment: `fread`? I've used that before. Very nice for storing and reading binary data from things like structs from a file. Would something like `fread(fbuf, sizeof(char), FILE_SIZE_LIMIT, f);` be sensible?

Comment: @B1KMusic what do you mean with "sensible" expression?

Comment: I mean it as in "reasonable" or "not inefficient/bug-prone".

Comment: It's OK. Anyway `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: @B1KMusic an edit for you in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

- Strictly speaking, `sscanf` will do most of the job in one line of code. I assume you want to avoid it for learning purposes.
- As in the part 1, the malformed input may result in the infinite loop.
- It doesn't look like the state machine is warranted here: the flow is strictly linear. A set of functions (`get_name(), get_int(), get_map()`) returning (along with the actual result) the breaking point is much more readable:

  ```
  fbp = get_name(fbp, nbuf);

  while (*fbp++ != '[')
      fbp++;
  fbp = get_int(fbp, &pd->width);

  while (*fbp++ != ',')
      fbp++;
  ```

etc.

Comment: Good idea on the functions! And thank you for addressing the `mode` system. In practice, though, I don't think a malformed file will result in an infinite loop, as eventually, `fbp` will have to reach the end of the buffer, and the eventual attempt to access a char that's out-of-bounds will (should) result in a `Segmentation fault`. Tested it with a file missing a `]`, and confirmed it crashes. Though the error is `*** stack smashing detected *** ... Aborted (core dumped)`. I suppose I could protect against that by adding a function to validate that the file is correctly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

1. Abstain from implementing the [Loop-Switch-Antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-switch_sequence).

   No, seriously.
   If you want to add comments, you can do so.
2. Test all functions which *can* fail for error, and handle that, for example by notifying the caller: `malloc` / `calloc`, `fopen`, `fgets`.
3. Avoid large stack-buffers. Also, use dynamic memory-allocation to avoid arbitrary limitations.
4. Actually check the above-mentioned limitations.
5. Don't zero memory just for the heck of it. There are more amusing ways to waste time.
6. Dito for reading a file: Use `fread` to read whole blocks instead of `fgetc` to read a single byte, thus incurring unavoidable overhead multiple times.

   As an aside, a `char` is the wrong data-type for saving the return-value of `fgetc`, use an `int` so `EOF` can be differentiated from `(char)-1`.
7. I would read the file in binary mode, meaning you can use `ftell` and `fseek` to get the size of the file, and restart from the beginning.

Comment: See? I knew there was something wrong with that. Something about it felt dirty, but I couldn't quite place it. Thank you for the source. On `#5`, is there a specific problem with `calloc`? I've learned to use it over `malloc` because it ensures that the data will be zero'd out, avoiding unexpected garbage. While `malloc` does tend to zero out memory (rather, the *OS kernel* zeros out the memory for security reasons), the C standard doesn't explicitly state that malloc *has* to zero out memory.

Comment: As for the aside...oops! I could have sworn I declared that as an int. I know exactly what you mean, because I've tried to use `char` for reading a binary file (e.g. implementing `xxd` for learning purposes), and for certain character values, the results are...rather unexpected.

Comment: Is there anything better about *expected* garbage? No (though debug-runtimes like to fill with a pattern likely making errors obvious, thus *not* zero). The rule is, don't initialize to some dummy value, that just defeats any chance for automatic tools to catch logic errors, assuming it can be optimized out. If it cannot, it also costs performance.